# How to load data from table and display in datagrid in VB.NET?

Tags: database, vb.net, datagrid

How to load data from database table and display in datagrid in VB.NET? I know how it is in C#. I am not familiar with vb.net.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you know C# then [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) try this

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx) shows you also in VB.NET how it works.

Comment: `datagrid` is what? ASP.NET, WinForm or WPF Control?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:-

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

In your event, write:-

```
    Dim con As SqlConnection

    Dim ada As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    con = New SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=sa;pwd=;database=databasename")
    con.Open()


    ada = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tablename", con)
    ada.Fill(ds)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: @Sun if my solution helps you to solve your problem, please accept it as your answer by clicking the check sign.